# linker: what is "NMAGIC" section of linked file and what is the aim of section alignment?

Tags: ld

ld man [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) say

> -n
>   --nmagic
>       Turn off page alignment of sections, and mark the output as "NMAGIC" if possible. 
>   -N
>   --omagic
>       Set the text and data sections to be readable and writable. Also, do not page-align the data segment, and disable linking against shared
>   libraries. If the output format supports Unix style magic numbers,
>   mark the output as "OMAGIC". Note: Although a writable text section is
>   allowed for PE-COFF targets, it does not conform to the format
>   specification published by Microsoft. 
>   --no-omagic
>       This option negates most of the effects of the -N option. It sets the text section to be read-only, and forces the data segment to be
>   page-aligned. Note - this option does not enable linking against
>   shared libraries. Use -Bdynamic for this.

I do understand that theses options are used to make the code (.text) section writable or not, but I don't get the point to align or not the sections, and what is a "NMAGIC" section

Answer (score 8):

On historic (PDP-11) Unix, an executable file's header began with a branch instruction that would jump past the header, to the actual start of the code. When Unix was ported to other processors, that initial PDP-11 branch instruction became fossilized as the "magic number" for the a.out(5) file format.  When "pure text" was introduced, initially to allow processes to share their code segments, a new magic number was introduced so that the kernel could tell the difference (there were some important Unix programs that relied on self-modifying code and thus needed to be loaded with writable code segments).  The old magic number (0407) was given the name "OMAGIC" -- "old magic" -- and the new magic number (0410) was given the name "NMAGIC", "new magic".  The data segment immediately follows the code segment in memory, so when the code segment is made read-only, it must be padded to a page boundary.

Various operating systems and file formats since then introduced other magic numbers; in the last FreeBSD releases to use a.out format, the normal formats were ZMAGIC and QMAGIC, which were introduced to allow page zero in the address space to be unmapped for safety (so that a null-pointer dereference would fault) while still allowing executables to be demand paged (i.e., mmap()ed into the process's address space).

So to answer your question more directly: NMAGIC and OMAGIC are different formats of executable files, not of individual sections.  They indicate the desired correspondence between the in-memory and on-disk layouts of the executable. (The reason these numbers are traditionally written in octal rather than hex or decimal is that octal is a natural representation for the instruction format on the PDP-11.)  GNU ld uses these names (only) as references to executable formats that have analogous features, even when you are not generating traditional a.out format -- which of course is quite rare today.  One particular benefit to using OMAGIC format is that it is more compact than any other format, which may matter in cases like boot loaders where space is limited, there is no demand paging, and there is also no room for any sort of padding.

Comment: Didn't get everything but it sounds more like an historical reason. If OMAGIC save space what is the drawback ? Why not everything if NMAGIC ?