# Bug in Clang code generation for member initializers in objects on x86-64 when page alignment off?

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, clang

**UPDATE3**: [Clang issue submitted](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/86895) as I am now confident that this is a previously unreported compiler bug. (There are many somewhat similar but distinct issues in the LLVM bug tracker.) Thanks to all who genuinely tried to help.

**UPDATE2**: It turns out this bug does **NOT** require the use of `-n` (`--nmagic`) option. The same crashes occur on binaries just built without using the C library (`-nostdlib` Clang option). So building NMAGIC binaries apparently has nothing to do with the problem.

**UPDATE**: LLVM's own linker, LLD, supports the `-n` (`--nmagic`) option so I installed it and gave it a try. The exact same segfault occurs. Since LLVM's own linker supports building NMAGIC binaries that strongly suggests that that it **should** work when user their compiler (Clang) too. I'll file a bug report.

**Original Post**:
I've come across a C++ issue where instantiating some objects in programs compiled by Clang segfaults. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help shed light on the issue.

Debugging suggests that Clang is generating SSE `movaps` instructions to initialize some char arrays and it's these instructions that appear to cause segfaults in some circumstances.

I've tested on multiple Linux systems with the binutils linker with both Clang 16 and Clang 17 with the same results. I'm not sure if the same problem occurs under other x86-64 operating systems or with other linkers. The problem does **not** occur when using versions of the GCC compiler instead of Clang.

The segfaults occur for some objects under the following minimum set of conditions:

- x86-64 code generation
- Optimization is enabled (-O1 or above)
- [**EDIT** - This was incorrect. The segfaults do **not** require the  `-n` (`--nmagic`) linker option. All that's necessary is to build a binary without the standard C library (`-nstdlib` option to Clang). I should also point out here that use of the `-fno-builtin` option makes no difference.]

Here is minimal code to reproduce. Compile with the following on an x86-64 Linux system [**EDIT**: removed unnecessary linker option]:

```
$ clang -O1 -nostdlib -fno-stack-protector -static clang_segv.s clang_segv.cc -o clang_segv
```

clang_segv.cc:

```
struct SegV
{
    void set(const char *s) { char *b = buf; while ( *s ) { *b++ = *s++; } *b = '\0'; }
    char  buf[128] = "";
    char *cursor   = buf; // needed for segfault
};

int
main()
{
    SegV v;
    v.set("aa");
    return 0;
}
```

clang_segv.s

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.global _start
_start:
    xor rbp,rbp             # Zero stack base pointer

    xor r9,r9
    pop rdi                 # Pop argc off stack -> rdi for 1st arg to main()
    mov rsi,rsp             # Argv @top of stack -> rsi for 2nd arg to main()
    call main               # Call main()... return result ends up in rax

    xor r9,r9
    mov rdi,rax             # Move main()'s return to 1st argument for exit()
    mov rax,231             # exit_group() syscall
    syscall                 # Tell kernel to exit program
```

This example is the minimum reproducer I could come up with and has no resemblance to the original code where I noticed the problem save that both have objects with char arrays. Changing the code around can mask or unmask the issue which usually suggests a coding error but I'm at a loss to find one in this simple example.

My debugger seems to think that the problems are the instructions that Clang is generating to initialize the 'buf' char array:
[Image of debugger suggesting issue with movaps instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuDiX.png).

My Debugger says that Clang generates the following code for the initialization of `char buf[128]`:

```
0x400171 xorps  %xmm0,%xmm0
0x400174 movaps %xmm0,-0x10(%rsp)
0x400179 movaps %xmm0,-0x20(%rsp)
0x40017e movaps %xmm0,-0x30(%rsp)
0x400183 movaps %xmm0,-0x40(%rsp)
0x400188 movaps %xmm0,-0x50(%rsp)
0x40018d movaps %xmm0,-0x60(%rsp)
0x400192 movaps %xmm0,-0x70(%rsp)
0x400197 movaps %xmm0,-0x80(%rsp)
0x40019c lea    -0x80(%rsp),%rax
```

and that the segfault is generated by the first movapps instruction.

Obviously, I expect that the initialization of the array shouldn't segfault.

It doesn't matter if in-class initialization is used as I do here in this example or if initializer-list initialization is used. Both methods suffer from the same problem.

I believe the problem might be a mismatch in how the code generated by clang **thinks** the members of the object are (should be) aligned versus how the members are **actually** aligned. I might be wrong about that but if I add alignas(32) to the structure or to the char array the problem goes away. I don't know why I'd need to align at 32 bytes. Perplexingly (to me), aligning at 16 bytes does not mask the problem.

The problem also goes away if I just tell Clang not to generate any SSE instructions with `-mno-sse` but I'd rather not lose those optimizations. In this case Clang uses `movq` instructions to initialize the array instead of `movaps`.

The problem also goes away if I forgo initialization of the char array member and do it manually in the constructor but of course that is less efficient.

At this point to me this looks like a compiler bug. Or am I just using it wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try reporting/asking it on [clang's official bug support](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues). They usually reply fast.

Comment: @user12002570 I haven't reported on the Clang bug tracker yet. I wanted to get some other eyes on it first as a sanity check before I report.

Comment: I'd guess it's simply that the compiler doesn't know that you're going to fiddle the linker settings to break the structure alignment so assumes that things are aligned when they're not

Comment: @CarlE.Thompson [Clang official issue support](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues) is the best way to do that as there you'll directly be asking experts of clang.

Comment: @AlanBirtles - I think the other way to look at it is that the compiler should not be making assumptions about alignment that it doesn't have control over.

Comment: @user12002570 Thanks for suggesting that I should just immediately submit a LLVM bug. I should have taken your advice as the rest of the comments here have not been useful. If you'd like submit that suggestion as an answer I'll accept it as you were the only one here who was genuinely helpful.

Comment: Please don't add the solution to the question. Post it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**:  In _start the stack is *already* aligned so by popping 8 bytes off in my startup code I was actually *misaligning* it before the call to main(). The SysV x86-64 ABI requires the stack be aligned prior to any calls so it is perfectly reasonable for Clang to assume that the stack is aligned a certain way upon entry to main() and to generate code accordingly. In other words: **This is not a bug**. (And, again, it has nothing to do with using the `--nmagic` linker option which is perfectly fine to use.)

Answer (score 0):

> Linked with the -n (--nmagic) linker option to turn off page alignment of ELF sections

Q. Doctor, it hurts when I do that.
A. Have you tried *not* doing that?

Clang (quite reasonably) assumes that it is dealing with *standard* linker behavior, which respects required object alignment.

When you use a special flag to tell linker to not do that, you are on your own.

> At this point to me this looks like a compiler bug.

It's not. If you report it to Clang developers, they are very likely to close it as "don't do that" user error.

> The problem also goes away if I just tell Clang not to generate any SSE instructions with -mno-sse but I'd rather not lose those optimizations.

1. There is *no guarantee* that other assumptions Clang makes will not cause a crash elsewhere.
2. As you see, the optimizations are incompatible with `-nmagic`. This brings us to the question: why on Earth would you do that? See also http://xyproblem.info

P.S. This problem is not limited to initialization -- Clang may unroll any random `memset` of a small fixed size with a series of `MOVAPS`. So even if you "fix" the known instances of this today, inconsequential changes to the source may make them re-appear tomorrow.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "standard linker behavior?" Which standard says that using a linker option supported by the linker itself, ELF, Linux, the assembler, other compilers, etc. is disallowed?

Comment: "Aligning sections" is the standard behavior. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61352891/50617 provides some clues on what NMAGIC files are -- this format has been obsolete 40 years ago.

Comment: Just repeating the phrase "standard behavior" doesn't really mean anything without an actual standard to give it substance. Why do you think using this linker option isn't allowed by the standard (it **is**)?

And you are incorrect when you imply that NMAGIC binaries are obsolete and no longer used on Linux. They are fully supported by Linux, the tools, the ELF format, and everything else and have various uses and are necessary on some platforms. Even LLVM's own linker, lld, fully supports the option. (And when using LLVM's own linker the segfault still occurs.)